# Template category.php with page (no posts)

Tags: categories, loop, pages

on my home page I have clickable images that redirect me to custom pages. On each page, I've made sure I can assign categories.

Now, I want to filter these categories by clicking on the button concerned. I have created my category.php template but I am blocking on the loop. Indeed, I don't have any problems when it comes to articles but when these are pages that have categories ...

Does anyone have an idea of ​​the loop style to use for pages and not articles?

Comment: HI Max! To summarise your question: you want to loop through all the pages in a particular category?

Comment: Hi mozboz, I have a parent page with id = 80 and I already have a loop that displays my child pages which are different projects to which I assign categories. I want to filter these child pages according to their categories.5